# ¿Cómo detectar esquinas redondeadas?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Estoy realizando un programa que identifique billetes de dólar. Necesito detectar el contorno de los billetes para luego trabajar con el contenido de cada uno, pero algunos billetes tienen esquinas ovaladas que el programa no consigue identificar correctamente. Aquí les dejo una imagen y el código:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


imagen= cv2.imread("dolares.jpg")
im2= cv2.resize(imagen, (1300,800))
gris= cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

canny= cv2.Canny(gris, 200, 400)
canny= cv2.dilate(canny, None, iterations=1)
canny= cv2.erode(canny, None, iterations=1)


cnts,_= cv2.findContours(canny,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in cnts:

    epsilon= 0.01*cv2.arcLength(c,True)
    approx= cv2.approxPolyDP(c, epsilon, True)
    
    x,y,w,h= cv2.boundingRect(approx)
    cv2.imshow("IM2", im2)

    if len(approx)==4:
        cv2.drawContours(im2, [approx], 0, (0,255,0), 2)
        cv2.putText(im2, "DOLAR", (x,y-5), 1, 1, (255,0,0), 1)
        print(len(approx))
    
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]